# Index of refraction calculus

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

Why is the refractive index the division of the speed of light in the vacuum by the speed of light in a determined medium? Doesn't it make more sense to express it parts per unit in order to have a more precise idea of how fast light propagates in a determined medium?

Comment: Wonder if you elaborate what you mean by ".... parts per unit in order to have a more precise idea of how fast light propagates in a determined medium"?

Answer (score 0):

In the attached figure which shows an incident wave incident at the boundary between two media empirically (and theoretically with some assumptions) between the (phase) speed of the wave in medium 1, $v_1$, and the speed in medium 2, $v_2$ is $\sin \theta_1/v_1 = \sin \theta_2/v_2$ which can be rewritten as $$\sin \theta_2 = \frac{v_1}{v_2} \sin \theta_1$$ Since for two given media, $v_1, v_2$ are known it is natural to introduce a refractive index by $n_{1,2} = \frac{v_1}{v_2}$. This notation has the advantage that if you know the speed of the wave in a third medium, say $v_3$ then if you know the refractive index between the media 2,3 you have the refractive index between 1,3 as $n_{1,3} = \frac{v_1}{v_3} = \frac{v_1}{v_2}\frac{v_2}{v_3} = n_{1,2} n_{2,3}$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is expressed only that way ... in length parts per unit of time, aka speed.  If into a denser medium, light has to propagate slowly.